# Supremum norm of Schwartz function in the terms of its Fourier transform

Tags: inequality, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

I have to prove that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\in(0,\epsilon)$ and $f\in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$
$$ 
||f||_{L^{\infty}} \leq C(n,\epsilon) \left[ |||\xi|^{\frac n2-\epsilon_1} \hat{f}(\xi)||_{L^2}+|||\xi|^{\frac n2+\epsilon_2} \hat{f}(\xi)||_{L^2}\right].
$$

I have two ideas but not solutions so far:

1) After rewriting LHS in the terms of $\hat{f}$ the problem is equivalent to (in terms of integrals)
$$
\forall_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \forall_{f\in S(\mathbb{R}^n)} |\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{it\cdot x} f(t)\,dt| \leq C(\epsilon,n)\left[ (\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |t|^{n-\varepsilon_1}|f(t)|^2\,dt)^{\frac 12} + (\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |t|^{n+\varepsilon_1}|f(t)|^2\,dt)^{\frac 12} \right].
$$

2) By Sobolev embedding theorem for any $\epsilon>0$
$$
||f||_{L^{\infty}}\leq C ||f||_{W^{\frac n2+\epsilon,2}}=C||(1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac n4+\frac{\epsilon}2}\hat{f}(\xi)||_{L^2}.
$$

Do you have any idea how to finish it?